# Issues displaying an image in a multipage window using tkinter

Tags: python, image, user-interface, tkinter

I apologize if the solution to this is obvious as I have limited experience with Tkinter and GUI's so I am using this project to teach myself. I have ran into an issue where I receive an error saying an image does not exist, the interesting part is is this was originally a single page window, I created another file that has multiple pages and tried to place my previous work into a frame on one of the pages. this apparently has caused some sort of image reference issue or its being garbage collected. I am using relative file paths, and the Images display as expected when used in a toplevel window. here is what I believe to be my relevant code

```
#located in CCGUI.py
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


class AbilityPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, switch_frame, Actor):
        super().__init__(master)

        tp_bg_1_1 = Image.open("Images/black2.png")

        self.tp_skill_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(tp_bg_1_1)

        options_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        options_frame.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        tk.Button(options_frame, text="save").pack(side="left")
        tk.Button(options_frame, text="load").pack(side="left")
        tk.Button(options_frame, text="new").pack(side="left")

        navigation_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        navigation_frame.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        tk.Label(navigation_frame, text="Abilities").pack(side="left")
        tk.Button(navigation_frame, text="Equipment", command=lambda: switch_frame(EquipmentPage)).pack(side="left")
        tk.Button(navigation_frame, text="Magic", command=lambda: switch_frame(MagicPage)).pack(side="left")

        TestImg = tk.Label(CC_frame, image=self.tp_skill_image).pack(anchor=tk.NW)

class EquipmentPage(tk.Frame):
#code for another page

class MagicPage(tk.Frame):
#code for another page

class CharacterSheet(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.title("Character Sheet Example")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        self.Actor = CC.Actor()

        for F in (AbilityPage, EquipmentPage, MagicPage):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(container, self.show_frame, self.Actor)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(AbilityPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame_name = cont.__name__
        frame = self.frames[frame_name]
        frame.tkraise()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = CharacterSheet()
    app.geometry("400x300")
    app.mainloop()

# the following is located in main.py

import tkinter as tk
from CCGUI import CharacterSheet


class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title("Main Window")

        # Add a button to open the character sheet
        open_sheet_button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Open Character Sheet", command=self.open_character_sheet)
        open_sheet_button.pack()

    def open_character_sheet(self):
        # Create a new instance of CharacterSheet when the button is pressed
        character_sheet_instance = CharacterSheet()
        character_sheet_instance.geometry("400x300")
        character_sheet_instance.mainloop()  # Use mainloop directly

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_instance = Main()
    main_instance.root.mainloop()
```

I have attempted to define redefine the images to self., I have tried to create them globally, and have tried to create them as class attributes, and attempted to prevent garbage collection however none seem to work I repeatedly get an error message _tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1 doesn't exist. note this code has been simplified and I have been trying to use multiple images in this GUI. I honestly did not expect to have an issue with this as using images seems as simple as Designate the filepath -> create it using ImageTK.PhotoImage() Any help or Ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: At least one problem is that you create more than one instance of `Tk`. Tkinter is designed to primarily have just one root window.

Comment: @BryanOakley So, I shouldn't have multiple windows, or is there a way to make an additional window that is not a root window, if so what is that called?

Comment: The second and subsequent windows can be instances of `Toplevel`.

Comment: @BryanOakley It worked! If you want to post the solution you can if not I can post the answer, wouldn't want to take credit if you wanted it!